# Implementation of Custom Logging Handler

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I was trying to implement a custom `StreamHandler`. The purpose of the custom handler is to add extra fields to the log message and make multiline error messages one line. This is what I came up so far:

```
class CustomStreamHandler(logging.StreamHandler):
    def __init__(self):
        logging.StreamHandler.__init__(self)
        self.formatter = '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(name)s %(message)s'\
            '\tcustomfiel_id=%(customfiel_id)s'\
            '\tcustomfiel_name=%(customfiel_name)s'

    def format(self, record):
        if record.exc_info:
            record.msg += repr(super().formatException(record.exc_info))
            record.exc_info = None
        result = super().format(record)
        return result

    def emit(self, record):
        pass
```

The `format` method will convert multi-line logs to one-line. But I am stuck. How can I add custom fields to all logs that use this handler. By the way currently it is not functioning as it is supposed to be. How should I continue?

Comment: "The fourth keyword argument is `extra` which can be used to pass a dictionary which is used to populate the `__dict__` of the `LogRecord` created for the logging event with user-defined attributes. These custom attributes can then be used as you like. For example, they could be incorporated into logged messages." - There's also an example just after that in the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.debug

Comment: @h4z3 First of all, `extra` is not suitable for my problem, I tried it. And even if I was going to use it, how should I complete the class implementation with `extra`?

Comment: There's literally an example which shows how IP is passed and formatted, using a formatter itself - you already have a formatter, so you only need to pass a dict with those values with those specific key names when you log message (using `.debug`, `.info` etc).

Comment: Also: "By the way currently it is not functioning as it is supposed to be." - could you elaborate? What isn't working?

Comment: @h4z3 when using `extra` every time calling `debug` you need to to pass dictionary like `extra=d`. and that is what i dont want to do.

Comment: @h4z3 and "not functioning as it is supposed to be" is pretty self-explanatory since I want from the class to format my logs.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can solve your problem using a custom `Formatter` and a custom `Filter`.

This `MyFormatter` makes sure that the exception is on one line:

```py
import logging

class MyFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    def format(self, record):
        if record.exc_info:
            record.msg += repr(super().formatException(record.exc_info))
            record.exc_info = None
        return logging.Formatter.format(self, record)
```

This `ContextFilter` adds context (ie attributes) to your `LogRecord` that can be used in the `MyFormatter`:

```py
class ContextFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        # you can make it dynamic here to add contextual information about
        # the record to log.
        import uuid
        record.customfiel_id = uuid.uuid4().hex[:10]
        record.customfiel_name = "foobar"
        return True
```

Then, put everything together:

```py
logger = logging.getLogger("foobar")
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()

myfilter = ContextFilter()
myformatter = MyFormatter(
    "%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(name)s %(message)s"
    "\tcustomfiel_id=%(customfiel_id)s\tcustomfiel_name=%(customfiel_name)s"
)

stream_handler.addFilter(myfilter)
stream_handler.setFormatter(myformatter)

logger.addHandler(stream_handler)

logger.info("This is a message.")
logger.info("This is another message with a different customfiel_id.")
```

It gives:

```
2023-02-07 17:24:07,981 INFO foobar This is a message.  customfiel_id=2f38f2d575        customfiel_name=foobar
2023-02-07 17:24:07,992 INFO foobar This is another message with a different customfiel_id.     customfiel_id=e3eabc8328        customfiel_name=foobar
```

Notice that the `customfiel_id` changes between logs. It is to show you that it can be dynamically changed.

---

See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#adding-contextual-information-to-your-logging-output) to go more in depth about context filters.